# Android with web services

Tags: android, web-services

How to get the wsdd XML script for Google Map?

Comment: This old question is too broad and shows no research effort. I will try to close it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use some web service which can give you latitude and longitude for city name. If about how to use web service than you have most of service where you get XML format as response you can parse it and get your needed information.

So it will help you to draw Google Map for city.